Extending normal filters
If $F$ is a $\kappa$-complete filter on some set $S$, and $F$ is generated by a basis of size $\lambda$, then $F$ extends to a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $S$ when we assume that $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-compact (Thm 22.17 in Kanamori's book).
What about normal filters? If $F$ is a $\kappa$-complete normal filter on $S$, it can be extended to a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter $U$, but can we assume that $U$ is normal as well?

In general, no, because $\kappa$ might not be $\lambda$-supercompact, even if it is $\lambda$-strongly compact. The two large cardinal notions are not provably equivalent (although it is an open question whether they are equiconsistent).
Suppose $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-strongly compact but not $\lambda$-supercompact, and consider the club filter $F$ on $S=P_\kappa\lambda$, consisting of the subsets $X\subseteq P_\kappa\lambda$ that contain a club set $C\subseteq X$. This is a normal filter, and fine, and so if $F$ could be extended to a normal ultrafilter $\mu$, it would mean $\kappa$ should be $\lambda$-supercompact, which it is not.
So it is consistent with ZFC relative to large cardinals that your desired property fails.

Thank you! Does this work in the other direction, i.e., if we assume $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact, then does my desired property hold?

I think even with $\lambda$-supercompactness, however, that the property fails. I think there will always be normal filters not contained in any normal ultrafilter. But I don't have an argument at hand...  I recall once thinking about this many years ago...

You must be reading my mind by responding to my question within 6 seconds...

Ha! I was writing the comment already before you had posted.

As Joel suggested in the comments, there are always normal filters that do not extend to normal ultrafilters. For example, let $F$ be the filter on $\kappa$ of all sets containing the set $S$ of singular cardinals below $\kappa$. Then $F$ is $\kappa$-complete and normal, but doesn't extend to a normal ultrafilter on $\kappa$. If it did, $\kappa$ would have to be measurable, but at the same time, the corresponding ultrapower would think $\kappa$ is singular, which is a contradiction.
